# How to show the related data of a gridview in new window/

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am doing a project in which i am getting data from a database and displaying in asp:gridview. i want to show a hyperlink column  in which i want to show a proper named hyperlink for example "View" and when the user click on "View" the data from the DataTextField property is displayed in detail on another page let say "WebForm1.aspx".i have  searched on net and have studied on msdn bt couldnt get. detailed help will appreciated .. piece of code as example will be helpful . thanks in advance. 
Example:
data in the database table
NewsID          NewsTitle       NewsArticle (NewArticle field contains large amount of data)

i want to show a proper link named("view"). when user click on the  view ,NewsArticle of the related record should be displayed in a new separate webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is for the hyperlink/url contained in each row of the grid view to contain the id of the record you want to view the detail, i.e.

```
<a href="webform1.aspx?id=12345">View</a>
```

then in the page_load event of the webform1.aspx you retrieve that record from the database and dispaly it on the page.

There are lots of ways to skin this cat, this is a relatively simple one. The code below is what you might use to generated the html above:

```
    <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Name" DataTextField="Id" DataNavigateUrlFields="DetailId" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="WebForm1.aspx?ID={0}">
    </asp:HyperLinkField>
```

Comment: Thank you very much .. i m getting it and i can see the required record id append with url on destination webform. but how can i get it there to retrieve the whole record in page_load event. its totally new to me plz help .

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Jquery you can user Dialogs

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/